# Forcing content type to application/json for python hug method

Tags: python, hug

AWS's SNS `POST`s a json body but sets the `CONTENT-TYPE` header to `text/plain`. Is there a way to tell hug to interpret `text/plain` as if it is `application/json` so I can get it to do the parsing and validation for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the input format handler for 'text/plain' with the one that handles json like so:

```
api = hug.API(__name__)
api.http.set_input_format('text/plain', hug.input_format.json)
```